# Unions of Infinity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have these two statements:

The union of countably infinitely many non-empty finite sets must be infinite.

The union of countably infinitely many finite sets can be uncountable.

I was wondering why they were both false? Surely the first one is like saying:

$\{1\}, \{1\}, \{1\}..... (\mathbb{N}$ times$)$ which because you could do this with $2$ or any other number and subset of any other size how can this not be infinite?

And for the second one by the same reasoning it would be infinite so uncountable?

If anyone could share their insight that would be great!

Comment: For the first statement:  the union of countably infinitely many copies of {$1$} is the finite set {$1$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you seem to have confused the concepts of *set* and *multiset*. In a set, nothing is repeated. The set $\{1,1,1\}=\{1\}$, for example. In a multiset, the number of repetitions matters. Your question deals with sets, not multisets. JW Tanner's comment gives a counterexample to the claim.

For the second case, since the sets themselves are countable, there is a bijection between them and the natural numbers. Place the natural numbers on the $x$-axis of some arbitrary plotting space. Since the number of sets is countable, do the same but place the natural numbers representing the sets on the $y$-axis. So each element of the new set has a unique ordered pair of natural numbers $(x,y)$ assigned to it. We now have a bijection between our new set (the union of the countably infinitely many countable sets) and the ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, which is known to be countable. Hence, the second claim is false.

Man, I *love* counting.

EDIT: Some values will be repeated in the construction in the second paragraph if the sets are not all mutually disjoint. Because we are forming a set, the repetitions are deleted and the claim holds.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your first statement is false. One counterexample is that the union of countably infinitely many copies of $\{1\}$ is $\{1\}$, which is clearly not an infinite set.

The second statement is also false. We can list all of the elements in the union by starting with the first set, listing all of its elements, then listing all of the elements in the second set that aren’t in the first, and so on... In this way, we will list all of the elements in the union, and so the union contains countable many elements.